# Файловый менеджер, взаимодействие файловой системы с mysql

Tags: mysql, файловая-система

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше организовать работу с файлами через web. Т.е. на сайте можно загружать любые типы файлов, при этом должна быть возможность постраничной разбивки. Сейчас все файлы выбираются с файлов системы без участия БД. Но проблема в том что, если это изображение, у него должно быть alt к примеру и title, следовательно это храниться в БД и вытягивается тупо по пути изображения, т.е. структура таблицы сейчас выглядит так:

```
id | path | props
------------------------
```

Соответственно в path я храню полный путь к файлу, к примеру /uploads/news/image.jpg В props у меня json строка со свойствами данного файла, т.к. у разных файлов они могут отличаться, делать отдельные столбцы для каждого свойства я не стал. Файлы я стягиваю как и писал без участия бд, напрямую с файловой системы, затем по path подтягию свойства, не знаю правильно ли это.

Еще одна проблема, это папки. Стоит ли хранить структуру папок в БД, используя nested sets к примеру ? Если да, дублировать ее с файловой системой или же в файловой системе хранить тупо все в одной папке, а в БД создавать "виртуальные" ? Как поступаете Вы ? Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом проектирования подобного рода вещей.

Comment: *Файлы я стягиваю как и писал без участия бд, напрямую с файловой системы, затем по path подтягию свойства, не знаю правильно ли это.* Скорее правильно было бы наоборот - получать из БД сведения о файле,в т.ч. и его местоположение в ФС, и уже потом по полученному пути грузить собственно файл. Но и так сойдёт, хотя это и поиск по текстовому полю... *Еще одна проблема, это папки. Стоит ли хранить структуру папок в БД* А они Вам зачем вообще-то? Кстати, при "обратной" схеме эта проблема отпадает сама собой...

Comment: _А они Вам зачем вообще-то?_ Люблю когда порядок :) К примеру есть несколько модулей, и изображения каждого из них в своей папке, а не все в куче. Да и насколько мне известно, чем больше файлов в одной папке, тем меньше скорость. Ну и при удалении модуля, папку изображений можно тупо удалить, не перебирая все файлы которые ему пренадлежат.

Comment: Может, вообще выкинуть БД, и взять вместо неё файловую систему с поддержкой метаданных?

Comment: В каком смысле ? Это ведь будет все крутиться на обычном хостинге, поэтому нужен самый универсальный вариант.